# Cast List alias to base in C#

Tags: c#

I write code on C# using russian language.
I create alias class for List

```
public class Список<T> : List<T>
{
}
```

And extension method to cast IEnumerable to this alias

```
public static class Расширение
{
    public static Список<T> ПривестиКСписку<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) 
    {
        return (Список<T>)(source.ToList());
    }
}
```

But casting not working -- InvalidCastException

Comment: your return type should be List<T>, and you don't need to cast it before returning IEnumerable to List,

Comment: Is your class names contains Greek letters?

Comment: @SonerGönül Russian, actually :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Oh, that's makes sense now `:)`

Comment: Could you post the code in english ? You'll probably get more answer this way.

Comment: "Список" means "List" in russian. It is synonym. I use russian for variables names, class names, fields and methods names (for to not writes comments) (and because I LIKE IT :)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Список<T>` is a `List<T>`. Opposite is not true - `List<T>` is not your custom class derived from list. So, you cannot simply cast instance of `List<T>` to some class derived from it.

So, you either should change return type of your extension method:

```
// which is odd, because ToList() already exists
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.ToList();
}
```

Or create new instance of derived class and return it:

```
public static Список<T> ПривестиКСписку<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var список = new Список<T>();
    список.AddRange(source);
    return список;
}
```

**NOTE!** Try not to use Russian language - it looks like [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) for those, who don't know Russian language, and it's really pain to switch between input languages when you are typing code.

Comment: Thank you if there is not another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to cast, while working with Generics

```
 public class Список<T> : List<T>
    {
    }
    public static class Расширение
    {
        public static List<T> ПривестиКСписку<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            return source.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast a base class object to its child class

```
public static class Расширение
{
    public static Список<T> ПривестиКСписку<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Список<T> list = new Список<T>();
        list.AddRange(source);
        return list;
    }
}
```